# openEmbedded sdk installation

Tags: sdk, openembedded

I am trying to install openEmbedded sdk for arm with libxml2 and freetype packages.

I hope that somebody here can give me good advice.

Question is about deploying sdk and giving include paths to the makefile.

To deploy sdk, I use /home/vincent/oe_dir3/setup-scripts/build/tmp-defaultsetup-eglibc-eglibc/deploy/sdk/oecore-i686-armv5te-toolchain-oe-core.0.sh and chose /home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/ directory.

First I am surprise I have no freetype or libxml2 include in the install directory.

```
vincent@electronic:~$ find /home/vincent/oe_dir3 -name "freetype" | grep "include/freetype"
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/setup-scripts/build/tmp-defaultsetup-eglibc-eglibc/sysroots/eukrea-cpuimx25/usr/include/freetype2/freetype
```

I continue to do the make with above path as include.

I meet following error :

```
 Linking... /home/vincent/eclipseProjects/sensigom/obj/parcoursMusical.o
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: cannot     find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: cannot     find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: cannot     find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: cannot    find -lstdc++
/home/vincent/oe_dir3/oecore-i686/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv5te-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: cannot    find -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know where and also in which documentation to search. If you have any idea I would be happy.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Freetype and libxml2 have to be added to your rootfs befor you generate the sdk.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "freetype libxml2"
```

They mustthen  appear in your sysroot

Comment: That effectively the way I found. If someone else have problem with include, I can only encourage them to study how work recipes.